# UCanAccess interfering with Java Logger output to console

Tags: logging, console, ucanaccess

I use UCanAccess for manipulating .mdb files. That works fine, but the Java standard Logger will not work. For example:

```
static Logger logger  = Logger.getLogger(Class.class.getName()); 
....
logger.info("important message"); //Console output works
```

After I use one UCanAccess method like

```
x = pst.executeUpdate();
logger.info("important message after insert")
```

the "important message" will not print on the console.

At first I thought that UCanAccess methods changed the logger handler so I tried

```
addHandler(new ConsoleHandler())
```

and I changed the Level to "all" with no success.

How can I fix this problem? :(

**Update**

Thanks for your help. I tried your solutions, but after the first UCanAccess method call the logger does not printer on screen. 
In this case after the:

```
x = pst.executeUpdate();
jlogger.info("insert");
```

the logger doesn't display the messages from all classes and methods after this `executeUpdate()`.
In all classes I use

```
static java.util.logging.Logger jlogger  = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Claas.class.getName());
```

to get the logger.

Comment: Duplicate of [UCanAccess/Jackcess exception when calling executeUpdate disable my Logger output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381687/ucanaccess-jackcess-exception-when-calling-executeupdate-disable-my-logger-outpu)